# Understanding a proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

I'm having some trouble understanding the second half of this proof that proves the following theorem:

```
Let f : A → R, where A ⊂ R, and suppose that c ∈ R is an
accumulation point of A. Then
limx→c
f(x) = L
if and only if
limn→∞
f(xn) = L.
for every sequence (xn) in A with xn 6= c for all n ∈ N such that
limn→∞
xn = c.
```

The first half of the proof:
`First assume that the limit exists and is equal to L. Suppose that (xn) is
any sequence in A with xn 6= c that converges to c, and let  > 0 be given. From
Definition 6.1, there exists δ > 0 such that |f(x) − L| <  whenever 0 < |x − c| < δ,
and since xn → c there exists N ∈ N such that 0 < |xn − c| < δ for all n > N. It
follows that |f(xn) − L| <  whenever n > N, so f(xn) → L as n → ∞.`

The first half of this proof I follow; we simply show that for a sequence, x_n, a delta exists when the sequence converges to c, which implies an epsilon must exist to show the limit of f(x_n) = L.

What I can't understand is the following (picture used as I don't know how to format is properly):

[Proof part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB5AC.png)

The basis of it is proving the converse of the above proof when the limit does not exist. I'm specifically stuck on where they pulled the inequality 0 < |x_n - c| < 1/n from: this doesn't seem to be a rule anywhere that I have found and I haven't the faintest how they got that result.

If anyone could give some tips on what's happening here it would be incredibly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given **any** $\delta$, we can always find at least one $x \in A$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-L| \geq \epsilon$.

This means in particular that for any $\delta_n = 1/n$, there exists $x_{n} \in A$ with $0<|x_n-c|< 1/n$ and $|f(x_n)-L| \geq \epsilon$. Now $x_n \to c$ , but $f(x_n)$ remains a fixed positive distance away from $L$, contradicting the hypothesis that $f(x_n) \to f(c)$.

We stipulate that $x_n$ satisfies $0<|x_n-c|< 1/n$ for convenience. We just want to construct a sequence $x_n$ tending to $c$ whose image $f(x_n)$ does not tend to $f(c)$, and picking $\delta_n = 1/n$ does the trick. There is nothing stopping us from constructing a more exotic sequence of $\delta_n$s. But there is no need to be extravagant.

Note that this direction is nontrivial, as it involves the axiom of (countable) choice.

Comment: So we're fixing delta to be equal to 1/n? Could this proof then also work if we fix delta = 1/20n for example?

Comment: Yes, it still works; the detail doesn't really matter. The key idea is to construct a sequence of $x_{n}$ which get arbitrarily close to $c$, but remain a fixed positive distance away from $L$, contradicting the sequential limit hypothesis.

Comment: The sequential limit hypothesis being the epsilon delta definition? As epsilon inequality is a direct result from our delta inequality? Just want to be clear on what we've contradicted as I'm kind of unsure.

Comment: You're right. Note that in your initial comment you said "fix $\delta = 1/n$"; I just want to point out that what we're really doing is we're picking out those $\delta$s that are of the form $1/n$, $n \in \mathbf{N}$.

Comment: Well the sequential limit hypothesis is the sequence definition, not the epsilon-delta one.

Comment: Alright, so would that mean if we take deltas of the form 3/n these would also work (As long as we state that we're using deltas of this form) for our contradiction? As in, as long as choose some form for our deltas to be of, this proof by contradiction will always hold.

So Epsilon - N not Epsilon - Delta? We've contradicted this definition as if the first inequality holds, the second must also hold (converge) - however it doesn't, thus a contradiction. Right?

Comment: Your goal is to prove that if the sequential definition (1) (for every sequence $x_n$ converging to $c$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $L$) holds, then it must be the case that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$ (2). So start by assuming (1). Now your goal is to show (2). To show (2), we need to show (3):  given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in A$, $0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$. This is difficult to prove, so we attempt a contradiction. Negate (3) to get (3'), and you get what I wrote above.

Comment: Ah I see, that actually made it alot clearer to see what we are doing. The contradiction is brought up by taking deltas of a specific type, which shows that if our first inequality holds, then the second must; but it doesn't by assumption, thus a contradiction. Thank you so much, I appreciate it :D

Comment: (3'): Given **any** $\delta$, we can always find at least one $x \in A$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-L| \geq \epsilon$. Using (3') we construct a sequence, showing that (1) does not hold (the details of constructing the "bad" sequence are in my answer). Then we arrive at a contradiction, because (1) and not (1) cannot both hold at the same time. This means that our assumption (3') is false, so (3) must be true.

Comment: You're welcome. Again, I wish to emphasise that this is a nontrivial thing to show, this argument was first presented by Cantor I think. When we choose our $x_n$s, we're secretly employing the axiom of choice.